# Vuetify slider: Change mouse cursor to pointer on hover and click

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuetify.js, mouse-cursor

Is there a way in `vuetify` to change the mouse cursor, when hovering over or clicking on the blue circular button element of the slider (`v-slider`)?

This is what it looks / behaves right now:

[image]

This is the way I want it to look / behave like:

[image]

I tried inline style, but it doesn't work: `style="cursor: pointer"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no props available to change cursor. Possible way to change cursor to add css to `.v-slider__thumb` class

```
.v-slider__thumb{
  cursor:grabbing;
  height:42px;
  width:42px;
}
```

Codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XGOqWm

Answer (score 2):

First add a class to the  then style as CSS. Exapmle below

```
<v-list>
   <v-list-item
       v-for="(item, index) in items"
          :key="index"
         >
           <v-list-item-title
             class="row-pointer"
         >{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item>
 </v-list>

<style scoped>
.row-pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the way I did it.  This method enables the cursor to change from `grab` to `grabbing` when the user is clicking-and-holding the draggable part of the slider.

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
  .my-slider-class >>> .v-slider {
    cursor: pointer;
    &:active {
      cursor: grabbing;
    }
    .v-slider__thumb {
      cursor: grab;
      &:active {
        cursor: grabbing;
      }
    }
  }
</style>
```